# i am trying to save an image png in a folder via os but nothing happens

Tags: python, operating-system, python-imaging-library

i am trying to save an image in a file so first, i open it then save it then i use path.join and the compiler works fine but nothing happens and the image stays where its and the folder stays empty.
here is my code:
note that directories are written fine because the folder and the image are in the source file
and note that the targeted folder is inside another folder

```
k=Image.open('Screenshot 2022-07-23 210655.png')
k=k.save('b.png')
j=os.path.join('yame','b.png')
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the path parts after the file has already been saved to the current working directory.

try this instead:

```
k=Image.open('Screenshot 2022-07-23 210655.png')
j=os.path.join('yame','b.png')
k.save(j)
```